# How to use salt and hash in login?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash, salt

I want to use salt and hash to create security login. I try to follow [this tutorial](http://blackbe.lt/php-secure-sessions/) and write own code but it always return false. Here is my code:

```
require_once 'application/third_party/Secure-Login/classes/Hashing.php';
require_once 'application/third_party/Secure-Login/classes/Salt.php';
$password = Hashing::create_hash('123456', Salt::random(12));
$old = '$2a$10$zuzycDw3Ack2cCoL3ds1sudJ2WioZ87.75ErLZVcZyh4d1hS2rHFu';

if (Hashing::validate($password, $old, Salt::random(12))) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

And two classes I included:

```
<?php

class Hashing {

    function __construct() {}

    /**
    * @param string $pass The user submitted password
    * @param string $hashed_pass The hashed password pulled from the database
    * @param string $salt The salt pulled from the database
    * @param string $hash_method The hashing method used to generate the hashed password
    */
    static function validate($pass, $hashed_pass, $salt, $hash_method = 'sha1') {
        if (function_exists('hash') && in_array($hash_method, hash_algos())) {
            return ($hashed_pass === hash($hash_method, $salt . $pass));
        }
        return ($hashed_pass === sha1($salt . $pass));
    }

    /**
     * Generates a secure, pseudo-random password with a safe fallback.
     */
    static function pseudo_rand($length) {
        if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
            $is_strong = false;
            $rand = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $is_strong);
            if ($is_strong === true) {
                return $rand;
            }
        }
        $rand = '';
        $sha = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $sha = hash('sha256', $sha . mt_rand());
            $chr = mt_rand(0, 62);
            $rand .= chr(hexdec($sha[$chr] . $sha[$chr + 1]));
        }
        return $rand;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a very secure hash. Uses blowfish by default with a fallback on SHA512.
     */
    static function create_hash($string, $salt = '', $hash_method = 'sha1', $stretch_cost = 10) {
    $salt = Hashing::pseudo_rand(128);
    $salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt)), 0, 22);
    if (function_exists('hash') && in_array($hash_method, hash_algos())) {
            return crypt($string, '$2a$' . $stretch_cost . '$' . $salt);
    }
    return Hashing::_create_hash($string, $salt);
    }

    /**
     * Fall-back SHA512 hashing algorithm with stretching.
     */
    static function _create_hash($password, $salt) {
        $hash = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 20000; $i++) {
            $hash = hash('sha512', $hash . $salt . $password);
        }
        return $hash;
    }

}

<?php

class Salt {

    public static function random($len = 8) {
    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+';
    $l = strlen($chars) - 1;
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $str .= $chars[rand(0, $l)];
    }
    return $str;
    }

}
```

Please check help me! I don't know where is wrong and how it works. Thank so much!

Comment: Why not use `password_hash()` ?

Comment: But I don't know how hash and salt works, and I want to everyone helps me check :(

Comment: Please don't roll your own crypto. As Mr. Alien suggests, you probably want to use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) rather than a custom class.

Comment: @Amber why should I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code, so i **strongly** suggest to use the functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to do the hashing.

Because you said that you want to understand how it works, here some tips:

```
static function create_hash($string, $salt = '', $hash_method = 'sha1', $stretch_cost = 10) {
  $salt = Hashing::pseudo_rand(128);
  $salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt)), 0, 22);
  if (function_exists('hash') && in_array($hash_method, hash_algos())) {
    return crypt($string, '$2a$' . $stretch_cost . '$' . $salt);
  }
  return Hashing::_create_hash($string, $salt);
}
```

This method first tries to use `crypt()` which is good, because it generates a BCrypt hash. The cost parameter will fail if it is smaller than 10, and the salt can be generated unsafe, and it uses ways too much entropy from the pool. Then it checks whether the `hash()` functions exists but this function is not at all made to hash passwords and has nothing to do with crypt().

Later for verification you do not use `crypt()`, instead you check with the `hash()` function, this is a different algorithm as before. Then the salt cannot be choosen freely to verify a password, instead you need the same salt that was used to generate the hash, the crypt() function actually did include this salt in the hash-value.

```
static function validate($pass, $hashed_pass, $salt, $hash_method = 'sha1') {
  if (function_exists('hash') && in_array($hash_method, hash_algos())) {
    return ($hashed_pass === hash($hash_method, $salt . $pass));
  }
  return ($hashed_pass === sha1($salt . $pass));
}
```

If you want to learn a bit more about password hashing, i would invite you to read my tutorial about [secure password storing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make your life easier. You can go for `PHPASS` library which provides you functions to use. You just need to create an object of the class and use the functions.

Check out these links:
You can download the library from here:
[Download PHPASS](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

You can get some more info from here:
[Sample usage of the library](https://phpbestpractices.org/#passwords)

Comment: yeah...its easy and most importantly it will work for versions even <=5.5.0 unlike password_hash() function which will work for versions only >= 5.5.0

Comment: You can use the function `password_hash()` with PHP 5.3.7 and later with the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php), it is written by the same author that wrote the password_hash() function. With a small change it even works for PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your example is that you use a new salt every time you want to verify a password, instead of using the old salt. In practice, you need to store the salt you used to hash a password in order to verify it.

Try the following code:

```
$salt = Salt::random(12);
$password = Hashing::create_hash('123456', $salt);
```

To verify:

```
if (Hashing::validate('123456', $password, $salt)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

Of course you will need to generate a NEW salt every time you want to hash a NEW password.

Comment: Your code is almost like my code. I wrote $password = Hashing::create_hash('123456', Salt::random(12)); and you wrote "$salt = Salt::random(12); $password = Hashing::create_hash('123456', $salt);". Do you know how do salt work?

Comment: It's not the same. Look at the verify function. I used the same salt that generated above to test. In your code, Salt::random(12) will generate a new salt every time it called. Try and let me know.

Comment: hehe, it's not the same but the result is the same. It returns false ;))

Comment: of course it should, if you still use the same value in `$old`, as it was hashed using a completely different salt. I edited my answer to make it more clear

Comment: if I always have to use the same salt but why do they write code to get random salt many time in code I wrote? I think I can use random salt ... I don't get it :(

Comment: each NEW password will get a NEW random salt.